# How to both exploit buffer overflow and pass parameter to system() function in this program?

Tags: c, arguments, parameter-passing, buffer-overflow

Firstly, I sorry about unlearly question, because of my bad english, I can not discrible it clearly. I also do not know what is it? whall is it called.

My problem below:

I write a program by C language:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()  {
    char buf[2],buf1[10];

    fgets(buf,2,stdin);
    fgets(buf1,10,stdin);

    puts(buf);
    puts(buf1);

    printf("Opening Shell...\n");

    system("/bin/dash");

    printf("\nEND\n");
    return 0;
}
```

My purpose is passing parameter to overflow buffer variables and inserting a command after **/bin/dash** to read some file that I do not own,.etc... I tried:
**pipe** :

```
python2.7 -c 'print "a"*12 + "\n" + " -c \"cat tes.c > show\""' |  /myprogram
```

My program run normally, but shellcode `-c "cat tes.c > show"` maybe do not be used.

I set all file and permission `7777`.

So, How can I insert shellcode after **/bin/dash**?

Thank for reading! Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `\0` at the end of `"/bin/dash"` and insert your code ending it with `\0`, since `\0` marks the end of a string.

Comment: If you want to you can also override "/bin/dash" depending on your needs. What's important that you insert your payload before the null character \0.

Comment: what about `\n` and `\x00`, is it the same?

Comment: \n is a new line character. If you're in a text editor and hit enter a \n will be inserted. \0 and \x00 are equal. The second one is hexadecimal denoted by the 'x'.

Comment: Thank, but It don't work :(. I have tried both `\0` and `\x00`, however the program maybe jump over `system(/bin/dash)` function :(.

Comment: Most likely your command in system is just wrong and therefore not executed.